# How to add an anchor hyperlink reference to my flash banner?

Tags: html, flash, flash-cs6

I just started learning how to create flash banners and I am in need of help! How can I add a hyperlink to my flash banner. I do not know where to type in the  tag in my flash banner. Here is my code:

```
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="600" height="100" id="psn" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="psn.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="psn.swf" width="600" height="100">
                    <param name="movie" value="psn.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
```

Comment: Do you want that when you click on something in your banner you will go to another site, page ?

Comment: Yes @akmozo, I don't know where to place the <a href=""></a> tag.

Comment: I tried to place it at the beginning and the end, so that it could catch all the flash banner. But did not work. I dunno if I am doing it right or not.

Comment: Do you have access to the source of you banner ?

Comment: I'm working on client-side. I created the banner on adobe flash cs6, and published it as an html code. I just want to add a hyperlink when I click on it. I want it to open a new tab for a specific website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open an hyper-link from your flash, you can use [`navigateToURL`](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) like this :

**For all your stage :** (you want that all your banner open the link ), visible example [here](http://www.fastswf.com/7bCO6gs) :

```
stage.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.example.com'), '_blank');
    }
)
```

**For a specific element in the stage :** (an on line example visible [here](http://www.fastswf.com/DgezGvw))

```
image.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.example.com/?img'), '_blank');
    }
)

red_rect.addEventListener(
    MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.example.com/?red'), '_blank');
    }
)
```

Of course in the second code (for elements), you have to disable the `stage MouseEvent` listener otherwise it will be fired for every click.

Hope that can help you.